# Check Coding convention tool?

Tags: apex

I am using Sublime for implementing Salesforce function. And I want to check my coding style or coding convention. Do Salesforce provide any app exchange for this? Thanks

Comment: You may try to use Village Chef plugin for Eclipse. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.6 You can configure rules the way you want. I believe there is a paid version as well.

Comment: Here's a sample rule set http://codescan.villagechief.com/eclipse/villagechief-pmd.xml

Comment: @SLman you could make a fine answer out of that

Answer (score 3):

Part of this is covered by [Force.com security scan](http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner). It's free and easy to use and I highly recommend it for all developers.